# If jquery has library, does C# also have?

Tags: c#

If jquery has library like [this](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) to have different actions, does C# also have?

Comment: This should clearly be posted to StackOverflow, not here. This is purely a programming question. You'd get much better luck there. But to answer your question: no. The jQuery API exists because of the way events are bound to web page components, and C#'s GUI libraries handle that quite differently.

Comment: @Max-P: You referred him back to StackOverflow, when I believe you mean to point him to other stack exchanges.

Comment: Yes it has a resource for listing out ALL the .net and MSDN API's that you can use whilst programming in c# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx for a catalogue of those API's

Comment: @m-y It was on SuperUser originally. It has been moved since my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is a framework but C# is a programing language. If you want C# language's reference look at MSDN's [C# Language Reference Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

But If you are looking for a framework's documentation you must search each of them individually. For example look at the [.Net Framework's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2(v=vs.110).aspx).

At last you could find lots of useful framework's documentation From [MSDN's library page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library)